# Azure API Management - Machine dependent client certificate creation

Tags: c#, azure, azure-api-management

I have created API and achieved functionality of subscription + certificate-based authetication with the help of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/control-authentication-with-apim/1-introduction.This implementation currently providing security to a particular user. If I provide the same subscription and certificate to another user, then also API is accessed.
Would you please explain how to avoid this scenario?
Would you please guide me on how to provide machine-based certified access by Azure API management?

Comment: According to his doc you can see the validation of the certificate, and you can know the reason for why any user with correct certificate(and subscription key, sub key is generated for api, it can be reused) can access API. And based on 'machine-based certificate' u said above, I think you may wanna a solution to validate different users. So would you like to use OAuth2.0 to secure access to APIs? https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPDWs.png

Answer (score 1):

According to the tutorial you provided in the question, there's several properties for users to set the validation policy. And the sample policy in the practice is based on **Thumbprint** like `<when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null || context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint != "desired-thumbprint")" >`

[image]

This leads to the scenario you mentioned in the question. And if you wanna set machine-based certified access policy, you need to change the judge condition. For example, you'd like to make your API be accessible for trusted subject, you can change the policy like this:

```
<inbound>
   <base />
   <choose>
       <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null 
       || context.Request.Certificate.Issuer != "CN=client-daemon.mycustomdomain.com, OU=Azure, O=tosokr.github.io, L=Amsterdam, S=North Holland, C=NL" 
       || context.Request.Certificate.SubjectName.Name != "CN=*.mycustomdomain.com")">
         <return-response>
             <set-status code="403" reason="Invalid client certificate" />
         </return-response>
       </when>
   </choose>
 </inbound>
```

More samples could refer to [this blog](https://aztoso.com/apim/client-certificates-authentication/).

Comment: Thanks for the valuable reply! I have already tried OAuth 2.0 and a recent Certificate issuer check. But my current requirement is related to different machine-based certificates for different users and that can't be resued by others. Would you please suggest any implementation ways in Azure Api management?

Comment: Have you have a way to generate different machine-based certificates for different users and that can't be resued by others? APIM policy is all the same, so I think the problem is generating certificate. You mean that you haven't found a way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I didn't find a way to generate machine-based certificate for APIM and how to use that in apim. Please guide how to generate and use certificate into apim.Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not an expert in certificate and I found a way to this problem for 2d but failed. If you found solution to this, could you pls add answer here?